# Using String.matches to match *, |, and spaces

Tags: java, string

This is what i am testing my method with that will check a string to see if its valid, i don't even know if matches is what i need to use. but i am trying to use it to check if a string contains only *, |, and spaces.

```
public class TallyTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(TallyString.isValidGroup("||**|*|"));
        System.out.println("Expected true");
        System.out.println(TallyString.evaluateGroup("||**|*|"));
        System.out.println("Expected 19");
        System.out.println(TallyString.makeGroup(19));
        System.out.println("Expected '***||||'");
    }
}
```

Comment: For the love of `$DEITY` learn to format your code properly.

Comment: Its hard to tell exactly what this is supposed to do or what the expected output shout be. Are you just trying to create the `isValidGroup(String)` method for now?

Comment: *"String.matches help!"* ... and where do you use `String#matches`? One upvote for this question in this state? Then I hope the upvoter will provide an answer without requesting more information.

Comment: yes i am trying to create the isValidGroup(String) now and if string.matches would be what i want to use to check if a String contains only *, |, and spaces.

Comment: @Ray-RayHow What is the current state of your `isValidGroup` method? Have you already tried to use `String#matches`? What are your results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Test
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       String s = "GT|!ll22";
       if(!s.matches("[*| ]+"))
           System.out.println("Incorrect");
   }
}
```

You can use String.matches to check if characters OTHER THAN certain ones that you want were entered.